# WCFサービスライブラリが見当たりません。

Tags: visual-studio, wpf

VisualStudio2013 for WebでWCFサービスライブラリのプロジェクトを作成したいと思い、下の画像のあたりで、WCFサービスライブラリの項目を探しているのですが見当たりません。
ライブラリのありかが分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

WCFサービス[image: 新規埔里ジェクト作成画面]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCFノードの中です。右上の検索ボックスでも出てきます。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
WCFノードの中にはWCFサービスアプリケーションしかありませんでした。